# push notifications with django and GCM

Tags: android, django, push-notification, server, google-cloud-messaging

I have a android client app, and my server is in django.

I want to implement push-notifications in the server, to notify the specific users when changes in data related to them are happening, for example.

I have found those links:

- https://django-gcm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html
- https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm
- https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications

Not really sure what which link I need and for what.

**An example for what I want is:**

A user makes a request to server and changes data, and the server sends a push notification to another user.

So what package should I install? and maybe any tutorials to follow??
I am looking for any info to help me.

thanks a lot!

**--- EDIT ----**

So I did as e4c5 suggested, and I have a table which contains Device ID coupled with user.

I register the device to the GCM when app is installed. 
I am also adding the Device_id to the table in my database (with the user field being `null` for now) and save the Device_id  in my client app as well.

**Now, when a user logs in, I send a request to my server which couples the logged in user with the Device ID.**

**When the user logs out - the user field is `null` again.**

Problem is - if UserA is currently logged out (not in my database) but should receive a notification - my server will look at the database -> Devices IDs table and wouldn't find the userA in any of the user fields (because he is currently logged out).

**As a result - the notification will be lost (my server would not send it to the GCM).**

**Best would be if when the user logs in again, he will get all the notifications that were sent to him while he was logged out.**

How can I do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that you don't need any packages at all. GCM is really simple, all you need to do is to make an [HTTP post](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http) to the url provided by google and that you can do with your favorite python http client library. If you don't have one yet, I recommend [python requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/). What most of the GCM libraries actually does is to add a thin layer on top of an http library such as this.

You will need to have a table to store the GCM registration ids. If people who use your app are asked to sign up for an account, your Django model might look something like this.

```
class Device(models.Model) :
    ANDROID = 1
    IPHONE = 2
    CHROME = 3
    OTHER = 4

    DEVICE_CHOICES = ( (ANDROID, 'Android'), (IPHONE, 'iPhone') , (CHROME,'Chrome'), (OTHER,'Others'))

    device_id = models.CharField(unique = True, max_length = 1024, default='')
    device_type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices = DEVICE_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True)
```

You might want to tap the [django login and logout signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals) to update the user field (or clear it) when someone logs in/out

Comment: thanks for your answer. I really dont know to what url I should send the request.. or with what headers. is there any tutorials for gcm with django?

Comment: thanks. but I do need a table of Devices coupled with users.. no? because for example user1 changes data related to user2. in the django app I need to POST to the google url with the user2 RegId (which should be available in the django app, meaning it should be already in the database).. is that correct? if its correct, I need to find the user2 RegId from the Auth.user..

Comment: okay thanks. one more issue, When i register from the client app to the GCM, its coupling the device with the Id. then - when I POST to the google url with this RegId, it will send push notification to the device. thing is, I have a login/logout in my app, so I guess the notification will be sent to the Device also if the user is logged out. is there a way around it? thanks a lot again!

Comment: thanks again! with this example, if a notification is sent to a user when he is logged out, the notification will be lost right? I mean, the notification won't be queued and received when user logs in, right?

Comment: How the notification is sent is tied to the user's registration_id and not the login state. A message that's queued to a particular registration id will be kept at their end if the device is offline and delivered when it comes back online. When the user logs out you should null the user field so that the device only recieved generic messages and not user specific ones

Comment: when you say "device is offline" and "back online", you mean to register and unregister  the user in the client app?for example in android - gcm.register or gcm.unregister? from what your wrote, it sounds like  nulling the user field in the  Device model makes the Device model offline? and therefore the notification will be queued?.. sorry for all the questions I just wanna make sure I understand the process

Comment: Offline as the device not being connected to internet or switched off. When you need to send out a GCM to a logged in user you would query the Device table for that user and then send the message to the registration_id but when the user field is null that means the user has logout so user specific messages will not be sent.

Comment: got it. but that means that any notifications that will be send to user while the user is logged out will be lost, because that my server side will see the user field is null and therefore won't send out the POST to the gcm, even though the notification did "happen"

Comment: Sounds like you ought to send two different kinds of notificaionts, generic ones for all users and specific ones for authenticated users. In any event the best approach is to use 'send-to-sync' https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#send-to-sync messages so that it doesn't really matter whether the user is authenticated or not

Comment: thanks again, I have another issue - I am editing the question because this comments are getting to long. would appreciate it if you would take a look and answer.

Answer (score 1):

A new answer to reflect the updated information, requirements in the edited question.

Queuing messages to be sent to a user when he is not logged in is moving away from the realm of GCM. This is simply a matter of maintaining a copy of messages on the server.

This can be easily achieved using Redis but can also be done by adding a new django model which saves the messages. ie. you are building a store and forward system now.

Soon as the login signal is fired, it should look in this newly created table and fire off the messages (provided that they are not stale)

Answer (score 1):

Even though this has been answered. I would recommend you to use a package that is actively developed and supported. There is no point in re-inventing the wheel. Also, you will get other advantages / functionalities that you may need in the future (For e.g. APNS support). I would recommend you to use either of the following:

1. [django-instapush](https://github.com/amyth/django-instapush)
2. [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications)

The former is developed and maintained by myself. Can be used to send both GCM and APNS notifications to android and IOS devices respectively and also support mongoengine if that's what you use for your django models. Here is a link to the [documentation](http://www.techstricks.com/django-push-notifications-mongoengine/).

Comment: Your answer is contradictive now because your project is not being actively developed

Comment: Both mentioned frameworks are currently dead projects. No releases for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this. You can send a notification to your Android app by sending a `GET` request to Google. Try this code:

```
notification_params={}
notification_params['event'] = event
notification_params['message'] = msg
notification_params['timstamp'] = datetime.datetime.now()

values = {
            "to": [list of android gcm registration keys],
            "collapse_key": "collapse key" ,
            "data": json.dumps(notification_params)
          }   

headers = {
           "UserAgent":"GCMServer",
           "Content-Type":"application/json",
           "Authorization":"key="+GCM API key
          }

requests.post(url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",data=values,headers=headers)
```