# how to connect Django server with android app for conitnous sending of data bidirectionally?

Tags: android, django, server, backend

I have developed a Django server and running on local host. now i want to connect my android app which collects some data in the background service and send that data to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [push notifications with django and GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393692/push-notifications-with-django-and-gcm)

Comment: i don't know about http requests. i want to send data continuously  for background service and if it matches with the database i want to push notifications to the app.